# Android studio app on target sdk 26 loses internet when switching to target sdk 29 28 or else

Tags: android, sdk

I have added required permissions on android manifest and everything was working fine until needed to update target sdk to be accepted on google play developer console as for now the minimum target sdk required is target sdk 28.

Do I need to change any thing here or what ?

This is my build grade:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hitech.legjislacioni"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }

        //Optionally configure your OneSignal IDs below
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "f5a80067-de84-4e01-bdd8-4c33f7e25e30",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "226084725464"]
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    jcenter();
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: Just found out that I was using links with http protocol and this was the reason links was not being accessible, after switching to https protocol everything was solved